# PHP Mysql select multiple tables diffrent row names

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have searched but didnt find what i need , so if some one can help me.. thanks allot.

I have 2 tables the same but the table names diffrent and the rows names are diffrent like this :

First table called **admins**:

admin_pid ,uname, admin_email , admin_fname , password , salt , admin_date_created , admin_date_create , admin_date_update ,admin_type , ip ,timestamp

the other table have the same data but the rows name are diffrent like this :

2nd table called **users**:

userid , username ,useremail ,user_fname , password , salt ,admin_user_create, user_date_created , user_date_update , userlevel , ip , timestamp

They both hold users details , but one table used for admin panel other for front site .

my corrent select from my login function on front site :

```
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT userid, username ,userlevel, ip, password, salt FROM users WHERE useremail = ? LIMIT 1")) { 
      $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // Bind "$email" to parameter.
      $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username,$usrlvl, $ip , $db_password, $salt); // get variables
```

i want to make them both either users and admins working on the front site .

Can i select them both so i will check from both table if user exsit?

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to check for results already on the internet. Mysql JOIN is a good plan here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm Also, if you want a conditional statement in the query, you can use this info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: no sry , i had spelling mistake , i need to select them both not join..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to use `UNION ALL`

```sql
SELECT userid, username ,userlevel, ip, password, salt 
  FROM
(
    SELECT userid, username, userlevel, ip, password, salt, useremail
      FROM users 
     UNION ALL
    SELECT admin_pid, uname, admin_type, ip, password, salt, admin_email
      FROM admins
) q
 WHERE useremail = ?
```

or

```sql
SELECT userid, username, userlevel, ip, password, salt
  FROM users 
 WHERE useremail = ? 
 UNION ALL
SELECT admin_pid, uname, admin_type, ip, password, salt
  FROM admins
 WHERE admin_email = ?
```

**Note:** In order for it to work number of columns, their positional order and data types from both `SELECT`s should be the same. You have no column with name `userlevel` in `admins` table, so I was improvising putting `admin_type` instead. If it's not the case you ether need to eliminate this column or return a constant value from second select for this column.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cfb8d/1)** demo

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that with the help of SQL UNION statement like that:

```
SELECT userid, username ,userlevel, ip, password, salt FROM users 
UNION
SELECT userid, username ,userlevel, ip, password, salt FROM admins
WHERE users.useremail = ? OR admins.useremail = ? LIMIT 1;
```